# NgModel.viewToModelUpdate not works when define a Form Control on Input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive, ngmodel

I want to change view and model data on an input with onBlur event by a directive.

I wrote this function to update view and model :

```
@HostListener('blur',['$event'])
  blur(e:Event){
    const target:HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
    const val = this.decimalPipe.transform(target.value.replace(/\,/g,''),'1.2-2');
    this.ngModel.viewToModelUpdate(Number(val.replace(/\,/g,'')));
    this.ngModel.valueAccessor.writeValue(val);
  }
```

This works well but when I want to define a form control on input `this.ngModel.viewToModelUpdate` is not impact to the model.

Form group code:

```
form = new FormGroup({amountInput:new FormControl('',Validators.min(this.traderService.trader.sMPA)),
  });
```

It seen ignore this function and set the model as string. How can I update model as number?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
this.ngModel.control.patchValue(Number(val.replace(/\,/g,'')));
```

instead of

```
this.ngModel.viewToModelUpdate(Number(val.replace(/\,/g,'')));
```

Had the same issue with custom directive for input with formControl on Angular 5.

Comment: Did you use viewChild to get ngModel properties?

Comment: As addition you can use `this.ngModel.valueAccessor.writeValue` to present a different view value.